# Ternery Operator

Tags: c, operators

```
unsigned char result= 0x0;
int maxX,maxY;
maxX = maxY = 0;
printf("enter input\n");
scanf("%d",&maxX);
scanf("%d",&maxY);
(maxX < 200)?(result | (1 )) :0;
(maxX > 1500)?(result | (1 <<1  )) :0;
(maxY < 200)?(result | (1 <<2  )) :0;
(maxY > 1500)?(result | (1 << 3)) :0;

printf("Result is %d\n",result);
```

Why `result` is always zero irrespective of `maxX` and `maxY` input?

Comment: You don't change `result` anywhere in your code. Add `result = (max... )) :0;`

Comment: none of these statements `(maxX < 200)?(result | (1 )) :0;` changes the value of result, they only compute some new values, which are discarded because you don't do anything with them. most likely you meant to put `result = ` before those expressions.

Answer (score 5):

You're evaluating the ternary operators, but you're not assigning them to anything.  This:

```
(result | (1 ))
```

Takes `result` and ORs it with 1, but doesn't do anything with the result.

If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, it will warn you of this:

```
/tmp/x1.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/x1.c:12: warning: statement with no effect
/tmp/x1.c:13: warning: statement with no effect
/tmp/x1.c:14: warning: statement with no effect
/tmp/x1.c:15: warning: statement with no effect
```

If you're expecting to take that result and assign it back to `result`, do this:

```
result |= (maxX < 200)?(1) :0;
result |= (maxX > 1500)?(1 <<1 ) :0;
result |= (maxY < 200)?(1 <<2 ) :0;
result |= (maxY > 1500)?(1 << 3) :0;
```

Answer (score 2):

All those `?:` lines completely lack side effects. You don't write to a variable anywhere, so they get optimized away. Your compiler should warn you about expressions having no effect.

Your code is 100% equivalent to this:

```
unsigned char result= 0x0;
int maxX,maxY;
maxX = maxY = 0;
printf("enter input\n");
scanf("%d",&maxX);
scanf("%d",&maxY);

printf("Result is %d\n",result);
```